# Chart.JS - show values on top of points

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, charts, chart.js

Good evening,

I'm trying to build a line chart that represents API response time. The problem is that I didn't find any solution in Chart.JS documentation. Is there any native solution or any solution using canvas api?

I want to get the chart looking like this:
[image]

Here is the code that I've used to generate the chart

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: hoursArrFirst,

            datasets: [{
                label: 'First Brand API',
                data: timeArrProftit,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.05)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.05)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(255, 59, 64, 1)'
                ]
            },{
                label: 'Second Brand API',
                data: timeArrSecond,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(132, 255, 99, 0.05)',
                    'rgba(64, 255, 159, 0.05)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(32,155,99,1)',
                    'rgba(64,155, 59, 1)'
                ]
            },{
                label: 'Third Brand API' ,
                data: timeArrThird,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(32, 99, 255, 0.05)',
                    'rgba(64, 59, 255, 0.05)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(32, 99, 120, 1)',
                    'rgba(64, 59, 120, 1)'
                ]
            }]


        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call a function during and after animation

```
var options = {
    onAnimationProgress: function() { drawDatasetPointsLabels() },
    onAnimationComplete: function() { drawDatasetPointsLabels() }
}
```

---

```
function drawDatasetPointsLabels() {
        ctx.font = '.9rem sans-serif';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#AAA';
        ctx.textAlign="center";
        $(Trends.datasets).each(function(idx,dataset){
            $(dataset.points).each(function(pdx,pointinfo){
                // First dataset is shifted off the scale line. 
                // Don't write to the canvas for the null placeholder.
                if ( pointinfo.value !== null ) { 
                    ctx.fillText(pointinfo.value,pointinfo.x,pointinfo.y - 15);
                }
            });
        });         
     }
```